# How to store many to many relationship with extra column data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, entity-attribute-value

[image: dbstructure]

in the above scenario 'signs and symptoms' is a multi selection and if 'others' selected  'specify-others' field must be filled . how to store this .
 what is the best table structure for performance and querying 
  Either to provide 15 columns in single table and store null if no value or to store  foreign key of symptoms in another table (in this strategy how to store 'others symptom' description column ie specify-other field data).

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal answer, your choice may depend on multiple factors including external issues, i.e. coding framework you use to support database (if any). The "classic" way to do it:

```
1. Patient table:

   id (PK)
   name

2. Symptom table:

    id (PK)
    symptom

3. Patient to Symptom table:

    id (PK)
    patient_id (FK)
    symptom_id (FK)
    other_symptoms (text)
```

But once again, any approach (including this one) has its own pros and cons and this is not a universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely exclude the *15 columns in a table option* because whenever a new symptom would be needed to be added, and **it will be** needed rather sooner than later, you'll have to:

- alter the table schema
- the code that displays the symptoms
- the code that inserts/updates patient records
- who knows what else.

I'd go with a classic [`many to many relationship`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)), with tables similar to:

- `patients`: patient_id, name, etc
- `symptoms`: symptom_id, name, description, etc
- `patient_symptoms`: patient_id, symptom_id

Even better would be an extra table:

- `visits`: doctor_id, patient_id, date, **other_symptoms**

And then, your `patient_symptoms` table can be related to an actual `visit` to a doctor:

- `patient_symptoms`: visit_id, symptom_id